# Update data in BigQuery from my Python script

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I have a large dataframe (BigFile) in Google BigQuery with 16m rows that looks like this:

```
    isbn             title      author          portfolio       course
0   1000000000123    Book 1    Author 1          Science        Biology    
1   1000000000124    Book 2    Author 2          Math           Statistics
2   1000000000125    Book 3    Author 3          English        Literature
```

I need to be able to make frequent, small changes to the larger set when a course is manually reclassified:

```
    isbn             title      author          portfolio       course
2   1000000000125    Book 3    Author 3          English        Composition
```

I work in Python and update/create tables using google.cloud import biqquery. I want to be able to update the larger table (BigFile) with the changes in the new, smaller table, without having to overwrite the entire larger table (BigFile). Ideally I would like to make those changes in Python instead of BQ, but I'm open to doing it in BQ if that is not an option.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use DML statements to apply changes from the smaller table in the big one by using MERGE. In python you can import the smaller table and then use the API to execute a query (client.query(QUERY)).

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement

https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquery/latest#perform-a-query